# Why does tornado not provide a decode_signed_value function?

Tags: python, api, encryption, tornado

I have been experimenting with authentication on APIs and was looking to pass a token with the request that uniquely identifies the user.

I want to know why there would only be an encode function `create_signed_value` and no `decode_signed_value` or `verify_signed_value`.

Are you expected to set it in a cookie and use the `get_secure_cookie` although I'm struggling with actually setting it too?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

To decode a signed value created using `create_signed_value`, you can pass the signed value to the `get_secure_cookie` method ([see docs](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.create_signed_value)):

```
signed_value = self.create_signed_value(name='auth', value='John Doe')

decoded_value = self.get_secure_cookie(name='auth', value=signed_value)
```

---

When I wrote the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61264316/1), I was unaware of the API which I've mentioned above.

Comment: Hi thanks and I've seen you before which seems unusual. I'm trying to set a cookie from a page called by javascript (specifically $.ajax) and it just does not set so I'm trying to use $.cookie to set the cookie and want the security of a signed value.

Comment: @FelixFarquharson Why not set the cookie on the server? You'll be able to access it later from javascript using `document.cookie`.

Comment: It will be because I dont want to reload everything. That might even be the point of ajax. I'm planning on setting it with document.cookie does that sound a bit like the answer.

Comment: @FelixFarquharson Yes you can set the cookie using `document.cookie` but that cookie will be sent to you by the server in the `Set-Cookie` header. Please see how cookies work in order to understand the process. I can update the answer with more explanation if you want.

Comment: i was just wondering if you would use another cryptographic library to deal with this situation or just use the decode_secure_token?

Comment: @FelixFarquharson In this case I'd set a cookie on the request using `set_sercure_cookie` method. It doesn't matter whether it's AJAX request or a regular request, browsers will save the cookie; you don't really have to reload the page.

Comment: @FelixFarquharson It's been a year, and if you're still curious, I've updated the answer with the proper API to decode a signed value. I apologise for my previous answer which was rather misinformed.

Comment: much appreciated